# Angular JavaScript coding issues

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular, angularjs-scope

Angular JS code.
2 lists, each list has items inside,click on an item of a list, the item removed from that list and add to another

looking for reusability:

```
$scope.move=function(index){
      $scope.list2.push($scope.list1[index]);
      $scope.list1.splice(index,1);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the help menu about what questions to aks or not to ask and how to ask good question. StackOverflow is not a community of code monkeys.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy as pie: https://plnkr.co/edit/xxTpvxB9GSwAqy25s5GN?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>List1</p>
  <div ng-repeat="item in list1">
    <a href="" ng-click="move($index);">{{item}}</a>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <p>List2</p>
  <div ng-repeat="item in list2">{{item}}</div>
</body>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.list1 = [
    "12",
    "13",
    "14"
    ];
    $scope.list2=["223"];

    $scope.move=function(index){
      $scope.list2.push($scope.list1[index]);
      $scope.list1.splice(index,1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help. It worked. but anyone can suggest that how to make this as reusable. because i'm looking to add to & fro...

Comment: i'm looking for reusability on below snippet.. like list1 and list2 should be resuable..  $scope.move=function(index){
      $scope.list2.push($scope.list1[index]);
      $scope.list1.splice(index,1);
    }